# Sylius customizing registration controller

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

Very simple question that makes me mad. 
I write in main file for routing `app/config/routing.yml`

```
sylius_user_registration:
    path: /register
    defaults: { _controller: MyBundle:Registration:register }
    methods: [GET, POST]
```

And my controller

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller
{
    public function registerAction(Request $request)
    {
        var_dump(111);die;
    }
}
```

And when I visit `myshop.loc/app_dev.php/register`, I see sylius register page. There is a simple customization. What I make wrong?

P.s.

- tried to clear cache
- routing file is declared in `app/config/config.yml`

Comment: Try to replace new route to the top of file, I think the original /register route fires firstly instead your route.Try to debug it with `php bin/console debug:router | grep registr`

Comment: @Dr.X forgot to add this in `P.s.`. Already Added in top of file and `debug:router` command returns `Defaults     | _controller: sylius.controller.customer:createAction  `. So my custom route invisible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sylius Bundles are registered first, therefore sylius routing is registered first and yours is ignored.

If you need to modify behaviour of `sylius.controller.customer:createAction`, instead of overloading routes, you need to extend customer controller via sylius resource system.

http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/customization/controller.html

http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/architecture/resource_layer.html